# For $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, the least value of the expression $x^2 + 2xy + 3y^2 - 6x + 6y$ is

Tags: calculus, quadratics

**The problem statement** : For $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, the least value of the expression $x^2 + 2xy + 3y^2 - 6x + 6y$ is -

I want to solve this using differential calculus.

**This is what I have tried so far :**

I am trying to differentiate it in terms of $x$, but it turns out that I am not able to implicitly differentiate it.

It would be great if someone could explain to me the solution to this problem.

Comment: Formatting tip:  You can enclose the entire mathematical expression between dollar signs.  For instance, typing `$x, y \in \mathbb{R}$`  produces $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: There is no equation in your post.

Answer (score 5):

I solved the question without noticing that the user of the original post wanted a solution using calculus; just treat it as an alternative solution.

---

Never forget the method of completing the square.
$$
\begin{aligned}
& x^2 + 2xy + 3y^2 - 6x + 6y \\
= {} & x^2 + (2yx - 6x) + 3y^2 + 6y \\
= {} & x^2 + 2x (y - 3) + (y - 3)^2 + 3y^2 + 6y - (y - 3)^2 \\
= {} & (x + y - 3)^2 + 2y^2 + 12y - 9 \\
= {} & (x + y - 3)^2 + 2(y^2 + 6y) - 9 \\
= {} & (x + y - 3)^2 + 2(y^2 + 6y + 9 - 9) - 9 \\
= {} & (x + y - 3)^2 + 2(y^2 + 6y + 9) - 27 \\
= {} & (x + y - 3)^2 + 2(y + 3)^2 - 27 \\
\geq {} & {-27}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence, on one hand, $x^2 + 2xy + 3y^2 - 6x + 6y \geq -27$ for real numbers $x$, $y$.

On the other hand, if $x$ and $y$ are taken to meet both the requirements that
$$
x + y - 3 = 0
$$
and that
$$
y + 3 = 0,
$$
which imply that $x = 6$ and $y = -3$, then
$$
x^2 + 2xy + 3y^2 - 6x + 6y \color{red}{=} -27.
$$

Hence the minimum is $-27$.

Comment: i already solved it using this method. BTW how did you solve this problem so fast ?

Comment: @ShivSatyam Well, it is because "practice makes perfect", I presume? I have used the method of completing the square so many times.

Comment: can you solve it using calculus ?

Comment: @ShivSatyam One can solve it using **multivariable calculus**; a solution using calculus has been written by Guillermo García Sáez.

Comment: i also tried to solve it using calculus but i was not able to differentiate it, i was not able to deal with dy/dx.

Comment: @ShivSatyam Why do you wish to deal with $\mathrm{d}y / \mathrm{d}x$? $x$ and $y$ are both **independent varibles**; it is not really meaningful to speak of $\mathrm{d}y / \mathrm{d}x$ here.

Answer (score 1):

Take $F(x,y)=x^2+2xy+3y^2-6x+6y.$ Their derivatives are $$F_x=2x+2y-6,\,F_y=2x+6y+6,$$ which is zero only if $x=6$ and $y=-3$. Their second order derivatives are $$F_{xx}=2,\,F_{yy}=6,\,F_{xy}=F_{yx}=2,$$ so the Hessian is \begin{pmatrix} 2&&2\\2&&6\end{pmatrix} which is positive definite, so the point is a global minimum with value $-27$.

Comment: can you please explain how did you differentiate it ?

Comment: I just differentiate the function $F$ as a typical function

Comment: how did you manage to eliminate dy/dx ?

Comment: Good answer. But I think you mean "positive definite Hessian" and not "definite positive Jacobian".

Comment: @ShivSatyam you need to learn the concept of [partial derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative).

Comment: @GauravChandan true! Thanks, im not English native

Answer (score 0):

I always propagate to use differential forms. A local extremum has a horizontal tangent space defined by the differential form

$$ 0 = \mathbb d \ (x^2 + 2 x y + 3 y^2 -6 x + 6 y) = 2 (x+y-3)  \mathbb d x + (6 y + 2 x +6) \mathbb d y $$

```
    Solve[x + y - 3 == 0 && 3 y + x + 3 == 0,{x,y}]
    {x -> 6, y -> -3}
    (x^2 + 2 x y + 3 y^2 -6 x + 6 y)/.{x -> 6, y -> -3}
    -27
```